# Is it possible for 1 to be O(n)

Tags: c++, big-o

Im learning O-notation, and I thought that 1 is O(1) because since 1 is considered a constant its Big-O would be 1. However, I'm reading that it can be O(n) as well. How is this possible? Would it be because is n = 1 then it would be the same?

Comment: You need to quote and cite. Providing a probably mangled version of what you read doesn't provide any opportunity for understanding or clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a function that is O(1) is also O(n) -- and O(n<sup>2</sup>), and O(e<sup>n</sup>), and so on. (And mathematically, you can think of `1` as a function that always has the same value.)

If you look at the [formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) of Big-O notation, you'll see (roughly stated) that a function *f(x)* is *O(g(x))* if *g(x)* exceeds *f(x)* by at least some constant factor as x goes to infinity. Quoting the linked article:

> Let *f* and *g* be two functions defined on some subset of the real
>   numbers. One writes
>
> *f(x)=O(g(x)) as x --> ∞
>
> if and only if there is a positive
>   constant *M* such that for all sufficiently large values of *x*, the
>   absolute value of *f(x)* is at most *M* multiplied by the absolute value
>   of *g(x)*. That is, *f(x) = O(g(x))* if and only if there exists a
>   positive real number *M* and a real number *x<sub>0</sub>* such that
>
> *|f(x)| ≤ M |g(x)| for all *x* ≥ *x<sub>0</sub>.

**However**, we rarely say that an O(1) function or algorithm is O(n), since saying it's O(n) is misleading and doesn't convey as much information. For example, we say that the Quicksort algorithm is O(n log n), and Bubblesort is O(n<sup>2</sup>). It's strictly true that Quicksort is also O(n<sup>2</sup>), but there's no point in saying so -- largely because a lot of people aren't familiar with the exact mathematical meaning of Big-O notation.

There's another notation called Big Theta (Θ) which applies tighter bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Big O Notation shows how the program complexity (it may be time, memory etc.) depends on the problem size.

O(1) means that the program complexity is independent of problem size. e.g. Accessing an array element. No matter which index you select, the time of accessing will be independent of the index.

O(n) means that the program complexity linearly depends on problem size. e.g. If you are linear searching an element in the array, you need to traverse most of the elements of the array. In the worst case, if element is not present in the array, you will be traversing the complete array.

If we increase the size of the array, the complexity say, time complexity will be different i.e. it will take more time to execute if we are traversing 100 elements than the time taken if we are traversing only 10 elements.

I hope this helps you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The Big O Notation is a mathematical way to explain the behaviour of a function near to a point or to infinity. This is a tool that is used in computer science to analyse the complexity of an algorithm. The complexity of an algorithm helps you analyse if your algorithm suits your situation and process your logic in a reasonable time.

But that does not answer your question. The question that if `n` is equal to `1` doesn't make sense in Big O notation. Like the name said, it's a notation and not a way to calculate in mathematics. Big O notation means to evaluate the behaviour of this algorithm near to infinite to tell which part of the algorithm is the most significant. For example, if an algorithm has a behaviour that can be represented by the function `2x^2 + 3x` the Big O notation says to take each part of this function and evaluate it near to infinite and take the function that is the most significant. So, by evaluating `2x^2` and `3x` we will see that `2x^2` will be a bigger infinite that `3x`. And the difference between `x^2` and `3x` are infinite too. So, if we eliminate the coefficients (that are not the variables part of function) we will have two complexities: `O(x^2)` and `O(x)`, so `O(n^2)` and `O(n)`. But we know that the most significant is the `O(n^2)`.

It's the same thing if inside a part of code, you have two complexities `O(1)` and `O(n)` the `O(n)` will be your algorithm complexity.

But if a `O(n)` complexity process only one element the behaviour will be equivalent to `O(1)`. But it doesn’t means that your algorithm has `O(1)` complexity.